# Cannot reset my password

Tags: password-recovery, gnome-control-center

### I cannot reset my password

I'm kinda stuck... I tried resetting my password with the recovery mode but it says error!

Does anybody know how to solve my problem???

I also could upload some screenshots of my problem if that would help?

It all started when I deleted the password after I tried editing my user account settings and it wants my password but I press enter and it says wrong password also when I download something it says that I have to provide password to 'authenticate' I press enter too but nothing... I type my old password too but it says 'WRONG!'

[image]

My user account and as you can see there is no password

[image]

I entered my password but you can see I cannot change it... What is going on?!?!

Comment: Hi friend, can I ask, why do you need to reset your password?

Comment: Ah because I cannot download or edit my user setting in Ubuntu

Comment: Please provide us with more information? Why, when, how etc. That screenshot might help

Comment: Here I edited it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a terminal try:

`passwd`

Then enter a new password.

Comment: Was going to say this ^^.

Comment: Ok I'll see if it works and 'Luis Alvarado' I'm not English I don't know the language very well and I couldn't upload pictures because I have 10 reputation ...

Comment: Haziz, Thanks if worked I always tried it in the Linux Ubuntu Recovery Mode. :) :) :) Thanks a lot